# It is true that $\|f\cdot \nabla^2f\|\leq \|\nabla f + \epsilon\|^2$?

Tags: inequality, jacobian, hessian-matrix

I want to know $\|f\cdot \nabla^2f\|\leq \|\nabla f + \epsilon\|^2$ is true or not,
where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $\|\cdot\|$ is norm operator, and $\epsilon$ is a small positive constant.

If it is true, please help me prove it. Otherwise, please give an counter-example.

Update: Any norm (2, Frobenius, ...) works for me. I am trying to prove $\left\Vert\nabla \frac{f}{\|\nabla f\|+\epsilon}\right\Vert\leq 1$. During the proof, I found that it is equivalent to prove $\|f\cdot \nabla^2f\|\leq \|\nabla f + \epsilon\|^2$.

Comment: Please explain what norms you’re talking about and what you’ve tried. In addition, how are you adding $\epsilon$ to the gradient?

Comment: Hi, Ted! I have updated the description.

Comment: When you write $\nabla^2$, you mean the Hessian and not the Laplacian? I still say $\|\nabla f+\epsilon\|$ makes no sense. The inequality seems unlikely. Multiply $f$ by a huge constant $c$; the left scales by $c^3$ and the right by $c^2$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**No, such an inequality cannot hold for general functions.**

There is a second-order term on the LHS, which has no reason to be bounded by the first-order one of the RHS.
You can refer to [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4685015/148248) for a precise construction of a counter-example with $n=1$.
The counter-example I constructed there also contradicts this inequality, as both are roughly equivalent as you established.